# Running webscraping Python file with HTML trigger on Azure

Tags: python, azure, web-scraping, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I currently am webscraping a website once per day to track changes through time, i wanted to move my project to an Azure cloud so I dont need to keep my PC on during the time of the scrape.

I've been exploring options and decided to use an Azure Function App, specifically an HTML trigger.
I've gotten my python file loaded in Visual Studio Code and linked it to my Azure portal, however I am now stuck on the actual step of running the python file that starts the scrape from the HTML trigger, as well as the process of storing those results in an Azure Table output binding that I have created.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is two questions in one.  Let's take it slow.  Have you tested the http triggered python function on your local machine yet?  Do you have the azure functions core tools installed?  See this guide. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01#verify-prerequisites

Comment: It seems to run locally, and I have functions core tools installed, the webscraper opens and sorts through the information I am looking at, I have even managed to receive some sort of response on an http output. I am trying to understand how to reroute this data that I am getting into an azure table.

Comment: That's great.  Now, to tackle your question in pieces... to deploy and test the code in Azure, did you complete step five of the guide I linked to?  That step deploys to azure, once complete, azure will provide a url that you can call to trigger the code.  Any issues, errors?

Comment: Hey sorry for late response. Locally I have gotten information webscraped to appear in the HTTP response, and have deployed the function to my Azure portal, however when I go to trigger the code via the link given I just get an HTTP 500 error. Sorry for late reply I have alot on the plate currently.

Comment: Honestly, you should break this question into smaller questions:  local azure function, remote azure function, function save to table.   Anyways, so local now works.  You can trigger the remote Azure function, and you are getting an 500. Check the logs in Azure, are there any error messages? Exceptions, etc?  What do those say?  ...

Comment: It seems like its some sort of ModuleNotFoundError. Locally it is finding a module that I import in my webscraping.py file, however on server it either does not exist, or is not in sys.path. Maybe the server is looking in the wrong place?

Comment: It is.  Server can't find the mode.  The python "module not found error" is fairly common.  If your initial question is resolved, I suggest  opening a new one focused on that issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have moved away from Azure after allocating some cheaper and easier to use resources. Azure is a pretty complicated framework to pick up and it was not worth spending a bunch of time on for my specific case