# Python Web Scraper in Azure

Tags: python, azure, web-scraping, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I have few web scrapers written in python to scrape data from ecommerce websites.
I want to run these scripts on Azure.
What's the best way out? I am looking into Azure functions and Azure Webjobs since I want to have a automated schedules to trigger my scripts.
Considering the amount of data to be scraped is huge, will Azure functions will be a costly affair ?
And how scalable will be webjobs to get this job done?
Are there any other cost effective ways to achieve the task ?
(I am New to Azure).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Selenium and HTTP Trigger for web **scraping**.

For Azure function cost on Consumption plan and Premium plan, you can refer to [Azure Functions pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) and **Reddit/Azure**: [Azure hosted Web Scraper, good or bad idea?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/iohi8c/azure_hosted_web_scraper_good_or_bad_idea/)

You can refer to [Run Selenium on azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/227623/run-selenium-on-azure-functions.html), [How to create a Selenium web scraper in Azure Functions](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-selenium-web-scraper-in-azure-functions-f156fd074503), [Running webscraping Python file with HTML trigger on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081800/running-webscraping-python-file-with-html-trigger-on-azure) and [Create a Website Scraper for Azure Functions](https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/2020/10/02/screen-scrape-dotnet-core-azure-function)

Comment: Hey appreciate the guidance, but I was wondering is there any other way a scraper can be hosted other than using azure functions , so that I can trigger the scripts from a webjob which reads a scheduler table to determine the schedule time and triggers accordingly(no of websites to be scrapped will keep on increasing). I want to avoid azure functions considering the fact that there is a huge data to be scrapped on a monthly basis, so it won't be that cost effective.

Comment: @ArunavNag were you able to find an alternative? I am also looking for a way to do this in a cost effective way.